# extract rownames and column names from correlation matrix using aspecefic value

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

My aim is to eliminate duplicates from a dataset.

For that I wrote a program that calculates correlations.

I want to take the name of the variables that have a correlation higher than a specific value I determine.

Here's one of the results I got.

```
            M926T709  M927T709_1  M927T709_2  M929T709
M926T709   1.0000000  0.9947082  0.9879702   0.8716944
M927T709_1 0.9947082  1.0000000  0.9955145   0.8785669
M927T709_2 0.9879702  0.9955145  1.0000000   0.8621052
M929T709   0.8716944  0.8785669  0.8621052   1.0000000
```

Let's say i want to obtain the name of variables that have percentage high than 95%

so i should  obtain this result

```
M926T709 , M927T709_1 , M927T709_2
```

Edit : the answer given by Ronak Shah worked well , but i need to obtain the results as vector so i can use the names after

Note, that I shouldn't analyze orthogonal results because they always equal to 1.

Please tell me if you need any clarification, also tell me if you want to see my entire program.

Comment: You can obtain this result with `rownames(df[rowSums(((df>=0.95) & (df<1)))!=0,])`but it is not straightforward depending on how you intend to use this result afterwards

Comment: @Basti: What about negative correlations? What about correlations of 1 outside the diagonal (though usually unlikely, it is still possible). Does you solution cover that?

Comment: Thank for your comment. Indeed it should partially cover other examples, my comment (and not answer) is fitting the above example. Feel free to post a more complete answer if you are not satisfied with this one, as actually I don't have enough skills and information about the dataset to propose a perfect answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `rowSums` and `colSums` you can count how many values are more than 0.95 in each row and column respectively and then return the names.

```
tmp <- mat > 0.95
diag(tmp) <- FALSE
names(Filter(function(x) x > 0, rowSums(tmp) > 0 | colSums(tmp) > 0))
#[1] "M926T709"   "M927T709_1" "M927T709_2"
```

Comment: Yes sure , can you tell me please , how can i return the names as vector so i can use the names after ? because i need to take the name of variables and do other work using the names ( i want to calculate the sum of this variables) , thank you

Comment: The output is already a vector, assign it to some variable which you can use later. `result <- names(Filter(function(x) x > 0, rowSums(tmp) > 0 | colSums(tmp) > 0))`

Answer (score 0):

Sample data: the `limit` and the correlation matrix `m` (with an added negative correlation for demonstration purposes):

```r
  limit <- 0.95
  m <- as.matrix( read.table(text = "
            M926T709  M927T709_1  M927T709_2  M929T709
M926T709   1.0000000  -0.9947082  0.9879702   0.8716944
M927T709_1 -0.9947082  1.0000000  0.9955145   0.8785669
M927T709_2 0.9879702  0.9955145  1.0000000   0.8621052
M929T709   0.8716944  0.8785669  0.8621052   1.0000000"))
```

Create a subset of the desired matrix and extract the row/column names.

```r
Target <- unique( # Remove any duplicates
  unlist( # merge subvectors of the `dimnames` list into one 
    dimnames( # gives all names of rows and columns of the matrix below
      # Create a subset of the matrix that ignores correlations < limit
      m[rowSums(abs(m) * upper.tri(m) > limit) > 0, # Rows
        colSums(abs(m) * upper.tri(m) > limit) > 0] # Columns
    ), 
    recursive = FALSE))

Target
#> [1] "M926T709"   "M927T709_1" "M927T709_2"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for you comment, i tried your solution but id didn't work on all data ,   i wrote a program that genrated a lot of correlation matrixs ,